# Adjusting for time zone with Material3 Datepicker

Tags: android, kotlin, datetimepicker, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm trying to create a simple app where the user needs to select a date. My issue is that it defaults to the date according to UTC time unless I add in the zone off set. My confusion is that I thought that `val currentZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())` would account for the time zone. I find my self having to add in the offset.  Other wise after 6:00PM it defaults to the next day.

[image]

```
val currentZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    val zoneOffset = currentZonedDateTime.offset
    val datePickerState = rememberDatePickerState(
        initialSelectedDateMillis = currentZonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli(),
        //initialSelectedDateMillis = currentZonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli() +    zoneOffset.totalSeconds * 1000,)
```

If I use the debugger it shows currentZonedDateTime set to America/Chicago. So why does it show UTC time unless I add in the code to add the zoneOffSet? Is there a better way to do this? It works if I add in the commented code. I'm confused why I need to.
[image]

Comment: I'm usure what your problem is. Is it that `currentZonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli()` provides the correct date but the `DatePicker` composable is displaying it wrong, or has this nothind to do with compose because somehow the date is already wrong in the first place?